# Spring MVC Redirect to Payment Provider Creates new Session on return

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC application that redirects to a payment provider, but on return a new session is created. I have a HttpSessionListener in place and I can see that the old session is not deleted, but a new one is created.

The application uses Spring MVC, Spring WebFlow and Spring Security.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

**1 Before navigation to payment provider**

***Request***

```
GET /my-web/registration/create/new?execution=e1s5 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61611
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:61611/my-web/registration/create/new?execution=e1s4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IE,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
Cookie: JSESSIONID=tramjzpvaxingk1wg4cnard
```

***Response***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

**2 On payment provider page**

***Request***

```
POST /payment HTTP/1.1
Host: payment-web-sogenactif.test.sips-atos.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7632
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: http://localhost:61611
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:61611/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IE,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
Cookie: JSESSIONID=mp4ukQkbRL1dKvvvg9FtqSQWDYWCs30f_zGHIdld.11v;
PAYPAGE_SESSIONID=mp4ukQkbRL1dKvvvg9FtqSQWDYWCs30f_zGHIdld.11v
```

***Response***

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2020 18:27:07 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: https://payment-web-sogenactif.test.sips-    atos.com/en/payment/card/capturecarddetails/ppc0
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: TS0170356f=013ca44a14a8f201e44f6f74d9c0ace0601b54972bf23c249719fac2d994b1425d459d88e58dd7e559b8e931405f2107ea54a0003c; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
```

**3 On return from payment provider**

***Request***

```
POST /my-web/payment/paypage/manual/response/L2lyLXdlYi9yZWdpc3RyYXRpb24vY3JlYXRlL25ldz9leGVjdXRpb249ZTFzNQ==/YWI3ZGEyOTMtMzhjOC00YjgwLWJlNTYtZDAxYjc3OGQ4MTJl HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61611
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3760
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IE,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
```

***Response***

```
Content-Length: 0
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://localhost:61611/my-web/registration/create/new?cacheKey=YWI3ZGEyOTMtMzhjOC00YjgwLWJlNTYtZDAxYjc3OGQ4MTJl
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=12ev6ciac4on91rondlvyrlycq;Path=/my-web;HttpOnly
```

**Initial Request**

***General***

```
Request URL: http://localhost:61611/my-web/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:61611
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

***Response Headers***

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:61611/my-web/home
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

***Request Headers***

```
GET /my-web/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61611
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:61611/my-web/loginPortal
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IE,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,la;q=0.7
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1qh2n4brclop3we7t5q7vyhfg
```

I think this is the problem:

When the redirect works, this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:61611/my-web/registration/create/new?   cacheKey=ZGEzYjkxZjEtZGUwNi00MDQyLWIxN2ItYmVkYmNjMjI2YmE0
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

When it fails the response has a new JSESSIONID

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://localhost:61611/my-web/registration/create/new?cacheKey=YmU5MjA4YWYtYzdhNy00ZDVjLTlmYTktNDYxNjI1N2FhMDRj
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=cmfsckwzljs5lme1csuragqu;Path=/ir-web;HttpOnly
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the application's session cookie is not being included in the request when it returns from the payment provider. A few things to check:

What does the application's session cookie look like when it is first created? Are there any [access restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies) on the cookie? For example, is it marked with the Secure flag and then perhaps the payment portal redirects to an http URL rather than https (this would mean the session cookie would not be sent when returning from the payment portal). Check the domain, path, and SameSite attributes for similar problems.

Another common problem (especially when developing) is that if your payment portal and application are running in the same domain, then the payment portal could override the session for the application. For example, if you run the application on localhost:8080 and the payment application on localhost:9090 they are isolated from a Same Origin point of view. However, cookies are only unique by domain and not port. This means that the payment portal's session could override the applications session. When it comes back to the application it sees an invalid session id (because it was created by the payment portal and thus the session is only valid for the payment portal) and ignores the invalid id and creates a new session. A way to work around this is to add a few hosts to your hosts config file and use different hosts for the application and the payment portal.

I'd recommend mapping out your HTTP requests/responses using the browser developer tools. Be sure to include the URLs and the cookies in the requests and responses in your mapping. Then track what happens to the application's session cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The development and payment portal are separate - the payment portal is 3rd party and not in our control. The session cookie is secure and has to remain so, for security reasons.

Comment: That makes sense that the session cookie needs to be secure. Then the question becomes, are you sure the payment portal is redirecting to https? If the portal redirects to http the secure cookie will not be sent and thus a new session will be created.

Comment: If you have trouble figuring it out, please post the request/responses using the browser developer tools.

Comment: The problem is intermittent and the redirect url is defined by us so it is correct. I'll post the request/response shortly

Comment: I've added the http requests and responses - above. There are three in total. The first is the request/response on my application before redirection to the payment provider. The second is the payment provider page, and the final request/response is the return to my site.

Comment: I think perhaps the problem might be moving from https to http. I am running my app on http (in dev) but the payment provider is configured for https.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with going to http. The application submits the JSESSIONID cookie over http in the first request which indicates to me that the secure attribute is not set.

Can re-post the request/reponses starting from a clean browser (clear your cookies) and ensure to include the request/response that creates the initial JSESSIONID cookie from the application.

Comment: I've added the initial request above. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have found the issue - see latest edition above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225834/discussion-between-rob-winch-and-sme).

Comment: SME and @rob-winch - What is the answer to this question? I am having the same problem with springboot.

Comment: @SME did you guys manage to resolve this issue? Running into the same behaviour...

Comment: We did, I can't remember what it was unfortunately. I'll have a think and get back to you